# Assets add file button not working (sometimes)

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, javascript

A user reported that when trying to add a photo in the control panel publish page it did not work. Clicking the "add file" button does nothing. I was able to verify that it did not work. I went to the Assets module settings and the file folders would not load any images. The waiting icon would just spin and spin.

Today I tried it again, and it did work. However she reported it still did not work for her. I again verified it worked. Now that I'm on a different computer (both of my are macs using safari and 10.8) it isn't working for me again. Opening the inspector I see this:
[image: error shown in inspector]

It used to work no problems, so this is new.

EE 2.5.3
Assets 1.1.5

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to Assets 2.1.3? Assets 2 has many more features and I'd be surprised if this issue persisted.

Comment: If it is still causing problems I'll give that a shot. It is a development site so I should get it to 2.6.x and update all the add ons as well. 

Is there something in 1.x that could cause this? Being confident it won't happen in 2.x hints at issues with 1.x, but I might be reading too much into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you and your client are accessing admin from the correct URL.

**www.yoursite.com/admin.php** could be different from **yoursite.com/admin.php** (with no www) depending on your install.

LISA WESS (Pixel and Tonic) responded to a similar question:

You were seeing JS cross-site security blocking, due the lack of 'www'. Your domains need to be consistent to avoid that problem - not just with P&T add-ons, at that. 
You should ensure that your installation always uses either www, or no www. Consistency there should help you avoid running into this.

Comment: it is a development site so we are accessing at dev.example.com. I'll try and see if I can get it to not work and look at the URL, but we've definitely been using dev for the subdomain and never www or nothing at all.

Comment: the bookmark she was using was http:// not https:// (why it didn't redirect to https is another issue....)